# Automate webpage that just work properly on IE using selenium on Chrome

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, internet-explorer, google-chrome-headless

I have a webpage that just work properly on IE, In other browsers I get a messed up layout, but I need to automate it with headless mode, can selenium work on chrome even with the layout messed?

Comment: Selenium has an IE browser you can use.

Answer (score 0):

Does this webpage work fine in Chrome? If this is the case, you can implement this requriement via chrome driver with Selenium.

But if this webpage only work correctly in IE, the you can only implement automation in IE or [Edge IE mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/edge-ie-mode) with Selenium. And Edge IE mode tabs actually running Internet Explorer, so they all use IE driver.

Here is a simple example:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.ie.service import Service

ieOptions = webdriver.IeOptions()
ieOptions.add_additional_option("ie.edgechromium", True)
ieOptions.add_additional_option("ie.edgepath",'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe')
ser = Service(r"C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\IEDriverServer.exe")
driver = webdriver.Ie(service = ser, options=ieOptions)

driver.maximize_window()
driver.get('https://www.google.com/')
```

**Note**: Please modify the `path` parameters according to your own situation.